# PostgreSQL: максимальное и текущее количество соединений

Tags: postgresql

Как можно узнать максимальное и текущее количество установленных соединений на сервере PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

За максимальное количество соединений отвечает параметр `max_connections`, получить который можно при помощи запроса

```
SHOW max_connections;
```

Количество подключенных к серверу соединений можно получить, выполнив запрос

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pg_stat_activity;
```